# Jaxb unmarshal - elements with minoccurs 0 which should be combined

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Paragraph>
    <ParaStyleName>headline_red</ParaStyleName>
    <TextStyleRanges>
        <TextStyleRange>
            <CharStyleName>[Ohne]</CharStyleName>
                <Contents>
                    <Content>inhalt</Content>
                    <Content>test text</Content>
                    <SpecialCharacter name="HARD_RETURN"/>
                    <Content> "text here</Content>
                    <SpecialCharacter name="DOUBLE_QUOTE_LEFT"/>
                </Contents>
        </TextStyleRange>
    </TextStyleRanges>
</Paragraph>
```

From this xml I need to obtain the Content part like this:
inhalt test text HARD_RETURN "text here DOUBLE_QUOTE_LEFT

For me the tag order inside of `<Contents>` is important, problem is that the number of  and `<SpecialCharacter>` is not always fix, and also the position of this tags is not fixed.

Note: I'm using JAXB for this and I have created the Model Class for Contents, for Content and for SpecialCharacter where in Contents I have as members `ArrayList<Content>` and `ArrayList<SpecialCharacter>` but in this case I can't linked the lists correct to keep the correct order of tags.

Please HELP me with a solution for this case.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to merge these two lists as follows:

```
@XmlElements(
    @XmlElement(name="Content", type=Content.class),
    @XmlElement(name="SpecialCharacter", type=SpecialCharacter.class)
})
public List<Object> getValues() {
    return values;
}
```